# Spring default page not going through Controller class

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In mvc-view-config.xml, i have `<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="countrys/countryList" />` and in Controller i have the code below. The idea is to load countrys/countryList.jsp when the site is first loaded. The problem is that it's showing the right jsp page, but the code doesn't call this showCountryList() in the controller class. But if I just do mysite.com/countrys or mysite.com/contrys/contryList, i can see the page also the code calls the showCountryList() function. What am I missing?

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/countrys", "/countrys/countryList"})
    public String showCountryList(Map<String, Object> model) {
        // Here we are returning an object of type 'Vets' rather than a collection of Vet objects 
        // so it is simpler for Object-Xml mapping

        System.out.println("---- in here-----------");

        Collection<Country> results = this.clinicService.getCountry();
        model.put("selections", results);

        return "countrys/countryList";        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This config element

```
<mvc:view-controller .../>
```

simply registers a [`ParameterizableViewController`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ParameterizableViewController.html) which

> [...] always returns a named view.

and you've mapped it to `/`. So when you send a request to `/`, that controller will be used, not the one which contains the handler method you've shown.

I don't see why you need that config element, just map your handler method to `/` in addition to the other paths

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/countrys", "/countrys/countryList"})
```

---

<sub>Also, the plural of 'country' is 'countries'.</sub>